# pass parameter from bash to mysql script

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to pass parameter from bash script to mysql script. The bash script is

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `ls *.symbol`
do
path=/home/qz/$file
script='/home/qz/sqls/load_eval.sql'
mysql -u qz -h compute-0-10 -pabc -e "set @pred = '$path'; source $script;" 
done
```

The load_eval.sql is

```
use biogrid;
load data local infile @pred into table lasp
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(score, symbols);
```

When running the bash script, I got error the message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL      server version for the right syntax to use near '@pred into table lasp ..
```

It seems the value of the parameter @pred is not passed into mysql script.

Comment: try to echo the mysql statement `echo "mysql ..."` and see if you see something wrong in the statement or probably post the echo here to help

Comment: @qing can you please run this script with -x and show the output? also change the mysql line to be mysql --verbose -u qz -h compute-0-10 -pabc -e "set \@pred = '$path'; source $script;" If you can post that to a pastebin i'm sure I can help out.

Comment: `path` is a bad choice for variable name, since it already has special meaning to the shell, use a different name, for example `filepath` or `fullname`

Comment: @MalcolmJones The output exceeds the size limit of comment box so I past them as two comments. Part I:ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2 in file: '/home/qz/sqls/load_eval.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@pred into table lasp
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(score, sym' at line 1

Comment: @MalcolmJones Part II:+ for file in '`ls *.symbol`'
+ filepath=/home/qz/lasp/61304.pair.symbol
+ script=/home/qz/sqls/load_eval.sql
+ mysql --verbose -u qz -h compute-0-10 -pabc -e 'set @pred='\''/home/qz/lasp/61304.pair.symbol'\''; source /home/qz/sqls/load_eval.sql;'
--------------
set @pred='/home/qz/lasp/61304.pair.symbol'
--------------

--------------
load data local infile @pred into table lasp
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(score, symbols)
--------------

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support session variables in a LOAD DATA INFILE statement like that.  This has been recognized as a feature request for quite some time (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39115), but the feature has never been implemented.

I would recommend using [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html) instead of doing the complex steps with mysql that you're doing.  The file's name must match the table's name, but you can trick this with a symbolic link:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.symbol
do
  path="/home/qz/$file"
  ln -s -f "$path" /tmp/lasp.txt
  mysqlimport -u qz -h compute-0-10 -pabc \
    --local --columns "score,symbols" /tmp/lasp.txt 
done
rm -f /tmp/lasp.txt
```

PS: No need use `ls`.  As you can see above, filename expansion works fine.

Comment: Use quotes around $path like this ``ln -s -f "$path" /tmp/lasp.txt`` . This way things wont break if path contains a space.